# How long should I wait for watercolor pan activation?

Tags: watercolor

Just got a Winsor & Newton watercolor set, i made a color table to test the colors. I spay the color with water as i do with schmincke ( horadam ) pans but when I tested the color was all so light, kind of the difference between student and professional color, so i double check the paper of the pans and it say Professional.

Do new pans need a lot of time before first activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add water to the pans you should agitate it a bit with the brush to get more color into suspension. There is no time delay, it is just a matter of how much pigment gets mixed with the water before you apply it to paper.

Comment: BTW - what probably happened here is that Scmincke makes more pigment saturated watercolor (pans) than W&N.